# how to fetch only the latest tags from a remote branch

Tags: git, git-remote

When running `git fetch --tags --depth 3 my_remote` from my corporate gigantic remote repo, the command downloads all the tags in all the branches.

I just want to have the latest tag, otherwise the log history gets cramped with meaningless (to me) remote branches from other developers, or release branches / tags.

AFAIK, there is also no way to know the latest branch/tag without actually downloading it with fetch. I mean, there are no commands such as `git log -10 my_remote my_branch` or `git log --remote my_remote my_branch -10`. With that information, I could just fetch the latest tags, explicitly naming them.

I wonder why such commands are not implemented (and if they are, it is not trivial to find out).

Anyhow, my best bet is to download a shallow mirror with:

```sh
cd /tmp
git clone --depth 8 --mirror <remote URL> temporaryMirror.git
```

Then I can browse it and even add it as a temporary remote, fetch everything or whatever I like, and when I am done, delete it. Repeat the operation any time I need to. But it feels extremely awkward and inefficient. I guess the consumed bandwith and resources are huge, both locally and remotely.

Comment: Please note that the command `git fetch --tags --depth 3 my_remote my_branch` has the same behaviour than the one that does not specify the branch: ALL tags are fetched

Comment: There's no such thing as "the latest tag". Or rather, every tag is "the latest tag". If that's not the case, which tag *is* the "latest" tag? How do you know? In any case, note that tags are not *in* branches. Tags are simply tags: identifiers in the `refs/tags/` name-space that generally provide the hash ID of either a commit directly (a "lightweight tag") or of an annotated tag object (annotated tags). Annotated tags go on to find an object, usually a commit, so that iether way you get a commit. Not a branch: just a commit.

Comment: It's certainly true that most *commits* are in branches. One commit—the root commit in your typical repository—is in *every* branch. A few commits, including tagged ones, may be in *no* branch at all. But if some commit C is in 7 branches, what does that tell you, if anything, about the new-ness of a tag that points to commit C? (This is something you'll need to decide for yourself so that you can implement whatever *you* might want here, for "latest tag": there's something you have in mind, it's just that Git doesn't know it, nor do I.)

Comment: thanks! There is no such thing as _the latest tag_. Then, I want to know the latest commit on a given branch. And then I want to see if this commit has a tag. Can I do that? And without fetching?

Comment: The latest commit on any given branch is that shown by the hash ID corresponding to the branch name (use `git for-each-ref`, or for a repository you haven't cloned yet, `git ls-remote`; see their documentation). The tag(s) that match that hash ID are those tags whose *commit* hash ID—as provided by the `^{}` suffix for annotated tags, or provided directly by the tag for lightweight tags—matches the branch hash ID; again, you can get these with `git ls-remote`.

Comment: oooh ok, `git ls-remote` was the command I was looking for - it also has a `--tags` option, I will try it and will write and answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but if you can organize your tags in structures with prefixes (`/`), then it's possible to fetch only the tags matching a given prefix easily:

```
git init
git remote set-head origin --auto
git fetch origin --depth 3 master
git fetch origin 'refs/tags/some-prefix/*:refs/tags/some-prefix/*'
git fetch origin 'refs/tags/other-prefix/*:refs/tags/other-prefix/*'
```

For example, you could make your tags follow a pattern of `YYYY-MM-DD/<actual-tagname>` and have some bash logic to only fetch a few latest prefixes.

Or maybe you have several types of tags (`production/...`, `test/...`) and you only need some of them.

It won't help with the tags created in the past, but if new tags start following some structure, it will give you a clean start going forward.

Answer (score 0):

After @torek reply and further investigation, the conclusion is that the best solutions for this problem are 2:

1. clone the repo, preferably bare and perhaps some shallow depth, as I was suggesting in the question (this uses lots of bandwidth and resources if the repo is huge as it is my case)
2. use github's online browsing features (i don't know if other git SaaS such as gitlab offer similar features)

As a side note, my corporate repo has some 14K tags in the master branch, but it has many other branches. This renders windows's tortoise git unusable even with a good computer.